# TeX capacity exceeded, input stack size=5000

Tags: errors

This is an error I am getting when trying to compile the document. Oddly, if i remove the text for either section and limit it to only one of the sections it compiles just fine but adding text causes the error. Thanks in advance. Here is the MWE:

```
%!TEX program = xelatex

\documentclass[10pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[hang,multiple]{footmisc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[polutonikogreek]{babel}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{dblfnote}
\usepackage{perpage} %the perpage package
\usepackage[center]{titlesec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\geometry{papersize={5.5in, 8.5in}}                % See geometry.pdf to learn the layout options. There are lots.
\renewcommand{\footnotelayout}{\RaggedRight} % for having raggedright footnotes
\onehalfspacing 
\setmainfont{OdysseaU}
\newfontfamily{\textgk}{OdysseaU}


\let\greektext\relax


\MakePerPage[1]{footnote} %the perpage package command
% \usepackage{parskip}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0} % sections are level 1



\vfuzz=30pt

\widowpenalty=10000
\raggedbottom


\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\chead{\leftmark}
\cfoot{\thepage}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{arabic}% Arabic page numbers (and reset to 1)
\setcounter{page}{8}

\begin{center}
Epistle to Diognetus
\end{center}

\section{Chapter 1}

\textbf{Diog. 1:1} \textgk{ἘΠΕΙΔΗ\footnote{\textgk{ἐπειδή} when, after} ὁρῶ, κράτιστε\footnote{\textgk{κράτιστος, η, ον} superl, most noble, most excellent} Διόγνητε,\footnote{\textgk{Διόγνητος, ου, ὁ} Diognetus} ὑπερεσπουδακότα\footnote{\textgk{ὑπερσπουδάζω} perf act ptcp m.s.acc., take great pains, be very eager} σε τὴν θεοσέβειαν\footnote{\textgk{θεοσέβεια, ας, ἡ} piety, godliness} τῶν Χριστιανῶν μαθεῖν\footnote{\textgk{μανθάνω} aor act inf, learn} καὶ πάνυ\footnote{\textgk{πάνυ} altogether, very} σαφῶς\footnote{\textgk{σαφῶς} clearly, exactly, very well} καὶ ἐπιμελῶς\footnote{\textgk{ἐπιμελῶς} carefully, diligently} πυνθανόμενον\footnote{\textgk{πυνθάνομαι} pres mid part m.s.acc., inquire, ask, learn} περὶ αὐτῶν, τίνι τε Θεῷ πεποιθότες καὶ πῶς θρησκεύοντες\footnote{\textgk{θρησκεύω} pres act ptcp m.p.nom, worship} αὐτὸν τόν τε κόσμον ὑπερορῶσι\footnote{\textgk{ὑπεροράω} pres act ind 3p, disdain, despise, disregard} πάντες καὶ θανάτου καταφρονοῦσι,\footnote{\textgk{καταφρονέω} pres act ind 3p, look down on, despise, scorn, treat with contempt} καὶ οὔτε τοὺς νομιζομένους\footnote{\textgk{νομίζω} pres mid ptcp m.p.acc., think believe, hold, consider} ὑπὸ τῶν Ἑλλήνων\footnote{\textgk{Ἕλλην, ηνος, ὁ} Greek} θεοὺς λογίζονται οὔτε τὴν Ἰουδαίων δεισιδαιμονίαν\footnote{\textgk{δεισιδαιμονία, ας, ἡ} religious scruple, religiosity, religion} φυλάσσουσι, καὶ τίνα τὴν φιλοστοργίαν\footnote{\textgk{φιλοστοργία, ας, ἡ} heartfelt love, strong affection} ἔχουσι πρὸς ἀλλήλους, καὶ τί δήποτε\footnote{\textgk{δήποτε} at any time} καινὸν τοῦτο γένος\footnote{\textgk{γένος, ους, τό} descendant, family, relative, nation, people, class, kind} ἢ ἐπιτήδευμα\footnote{\textgk{ἐπιτήδευμα, ατος, τό} pursuit, way of living} εἰσῆλθεν εἰς τὸν βίον\footnote{\textgk{βίος, ου, ὁ} life} νῦν καὶ οὐ πρότερον;\footnote{\textgk{πρότερος, α, ον} former, earlier}} \textbf{2} \textgk{ἀποδέχομαί\footnote{\textgk{ἀποδέχομαι} pres mid ind 1s, welcome, accept, recognize, acknowledge, praise} γε\footnote{\textgk{γέ} at least, even, indeed} τῆς προθυμίας\footnote{\textgk{προθυμία, ας, ἡ} willingness, readiness, goodwill} σε ταύτης καὶ παρὰ τοῦ Θεοῦ, τοῦ καὶ τὸ λέγειν καὶ τὸ ἀκούειν ἡμῖν χορηγοῦντος,\footnote{\textgk{χορηγέω} pres act ptcp m.s.gen., provide, supply} αἰτοῦμαι δοθῆναι ἐμοὶ μὲν εἰπεῖν οὕτως ὡς μάλιστα\footnote{\textgk{μάλιστα} superl, most of all, above all, especially, most assuredly, certainly} ἂν ἀκούσαντά σε βελτίω\footnote{\textgk{βελτίων, ον} superl, better} γενέσθαι, σοί τε οὕτως ἀκοῦσαι ὡς μὴ λυπηθῆναι\footnote{\textgk{λυπέω} aor pass inf, vex, irritate, offend, insult, be sad, be distressed, grieve}  τὸν εἰπόντα.}

\section{Chapter 2}

\textbf{2:1} \textgk{Ἄγε δή,\footnote{\textgk{δή} indeed, now, then, therefore} καθάρας\footnote{\textgk{καθαίρω} aor act ptcp m.s.nom., make clean} σεαυτὸν ἀπὸ πάντων τῶν προκατεχόντων\footnote{\textgk{προκατέχω} pres act ptcp m.p.gen., gain possession of previously, occupy previously} σου τὴν διάνοιαν\footnote{\textgk{διάνοια, ας, ἡ} understanding, intelligence, mind, disposition, thought} λογισμῶν,\footnote{\textgk{λογισμός, οῦ, ὁ} calculation, reasoning, reflection, thought, reasoning power, wisdom} καὶ τὴν ἀπατῶσάν\footnote{\textgk{ἀπατάω} pres act ptcp f.s.acc., deceive, mislead} σε συνήθειαν\footnote{\textgk{συνήθεια, ας, ἡ} friendship, fellowship, intimacy, custom, habit, usage} ἀποσκευασάμενος,\footnote{\textgk{ἀποσκευάζω} aor mid ptcp m.s.nom., lay aside, get rid of} καὶ γενόμενος ὥσπερ ἐξ ἀρχῆς καινὸς ἄνθρωπος, ὡς ἂν καὶ λόγου καινοῦ, καθάπερ\footnote{\textgk{καθάπερ} just as} καὶ αὐτὸς ὡμολόγησας,\footnote{\textgk{ὁμολογέω} aor act ind 2s, promise, assure, agree, grant, admit, confess} ἀκροατὴς\footnote{\textgk{ἀκροατής, οῦ, ὁ} a hearer}  ἐσόμενος· ἴδε\footnote{\textgk{ἴδε} look!, see!, take notice, pay attention!} μὴ μόνον τοῖς ὀφθαλμοῖς ἀλλὰ καὶ τῇ φρονήσει\footnote{\textgk{φρόνησις, εως, ἡ} way of thinking, (frame of) mind, understanding, insight, intelligence} τίνος ὑποστάσεως\footnote{\textgk{ὑπόστασις, εως, ἡ} substantial nature, essence, actual being, reality} ἢ τίνος εἴδους\footnote{\textgk{εἶδος, ους, τό} form, outward appearance, kind, seeing, sight} τυγχάνουσιν\footnote{\textgk{τυγχάνω} pres act ind 3p, meet, attain, gain, find, experience, happen, turn out} οὓς ἐρεῖτε καὶ νομίζετε\footnote{\textgk{νομίζω} pres act ind 2p., have in common use, think, believe, hold, consider} Θεούς.} \textbf{2} \textgk{οὐχ ὁ μέν τις λίθος ἐστὶν ὅμοιος τῷ πατουμένῳ,\footnote{\textgk{πατέω} pres mid ptcp m.s.dat., tread, walk, trample|} ὁ δ᾿ ἐστὶ χαλκὸς\footnote{\textgk{χαλκός, οῦ, ὁ} brass, bronze} οὐ κρείσσων\footnote{\textgk{κρείττων, ον} more prominent, higher in rank, preferable, better, more useful, more advantageous} τῶν εἰς τὴν χρῆσιν\footnote{\textgk{χρῆσις, εως, ἡ} use, usage, usefulness} ἡμῖν κεχαλκευμένων\footnote{\textgk{χαλκεύω} perf mid ptcp n.p.gen., forge} σκευῶν,\footnote{\textgk{σκεῦος, ους, τό} thing, object, vessel, jar, dish, instrument} ὁ δὲ ξύλον\footnote{\textgk{ξύλον, ου, τό} wood, tree} ἤδη καὶ σεσηπός,\footnote{\textgk{σήπω} perf act ptcp n.s.nom., decay, rot} ὁ δὲ ἄργυρος\footnote{\textgk{ἄργυρος, ου, ὁ} silver, silver money} χρῄζων\footnote{\textgk{χρῄζω} pres act ptcp m.s.nom., need, (have) need (of)} ἀνθρώπου τοῦ φυλάξαντος ἵνα μὴ κλαπῇ,\footnote{\textgk{κλέπτω} aor pass sub 3s, steal} ὁ δὲ σίδηρος\footnote{\textgk{σίδηρος, ου, ὁ} iron} ὑπὸ ἰοῦ\footnote{\textgk{ἰός, οῦ, ὁ} poison, venom, corrosion, rust} διεφθαρμένος,\footnote{\textgk{διαφθείρω} perf mid ptcp m.s.nom., spoil, destroy, deprave, ruin} ὁ δὲ ὄστρακον,\footnote{\textgk{ὄστρακον, ου, τό} baked clay, pottery} οὐδὲν τοῦ κατεσκευασμένου\footnote{\textgk{κατασκευάζω} perf mid ptcp m.s.gen., make ready, prepare, build, construct, erect, create, furnish, equip} πρὸς τὴν ἀτιμοτάτην\footnote{\textgk{ἄτιμος, ον} superl, dishonored, despised, insignificant} ὑπηρεσίαν εὐπρεπέστερον;\footnote{\textgk{εὐπρεπής, ές} looking well, suited}} \textbf{3} \textgk{οὐ φθαρτῆς\footnote{\textgk{φθαρτός, ή, όν} perishable} ὕλης\footnote{\textgk{ὕλη, ης, ἡ} forest, wood, material, matter, stuff} ταῦτα πάντα; οὐχ ὑπὸ σιδήρου\footnote{\textgk{σίδηρος, ου, ὁ} iron} καὶ πυρὸς κεχαλκευμένα;\footnote{\textgk{χαλκεύω} perf mid ptcp n.p.nom., forge} οὐχ ὃ μὲν αὐτῶν λιθοξόος\footnote{\textgk{λιθοξόος, ου, ὁ} sculptor} ὃ δὲ χαλκεὺς\footnote{\textgk{χαλκεύς, ἐως, ὁ} (black)smith, metalworker} ὃ δὲ ἀργυροκόπος\footnote{\textgk{ἀργυροκόπος, ου, ὁ} silversmith} ὃ δὲ κεραμεὺς\footnote{\textgk{κεραμεύς, ἐως, ὁ} potter} ἔπλασεν;\footnote{\textgk{πλάσσω} aor act ind 3s, form, mold, shape} οὐ πρὶν\footnote{\textgk{πρίν} before} ἢ ταῖς τέχναις\footnote{\textgk{τέχνη, ης, ἡ} skill, trade} τούτων εἰς τὴν μορφὴν\footnote{\textgk{μορφή, ῆς, ἡ} form, outward appearance, shape} ταύτην ἐκτυπωθῆναι\footnote{\textgk{ἐκτυπόω} aor pass inf, shape} ἦν ἕκαστον αὐτῶν ἑκάστῳ εἰκάζειν\footnote{\textgk{εἰκάζω} pres act inf, suppose, imagine} μεταμεμορφωμένον;\footnote{\textgk{μεταμορφόω} perf mid ptcp n.s.acc., be transfigured, be changed, be transformed} οὐ τὰ νῦν ἐκ τῆς αὐτῆς ὕλης\footnote{\textgk{ὕλη, ης, ἡ} forest, wood, material, matter, stuff} ὄντα σκεύη\footnote{\textgk{σκεῦος, ους, τό} thing, object, vessel, jar, dish, instrument} γένοιτ᾿ ἄν, εἰ τύχοι\footnote{\textgk{τυγχάνω} aor act opt 3s, meet, attain, gain, find, experience, happen, turn out} τῶν αὐτῶν τεχνιτῶν,\footnote{\textgk{τεχνίτης, ου, ὁ} craftsperson, artisan, designer} ὅμοια τοιούτοις;} \textbf{4} \textgk{οὐ ταῦτα πάλιν τὰ νῦν ὑφ᾿ ὑμῶν προσκυνούμενα δύναιτ᾿ ἂν ὑπὸ ἀνθρώπων σκεύη\footnote{\textgk{σκεῦος, ους, τό} thing, object, vessel, jar, dish, instrument} ὅμοια γενέσθαι τοῖς λοιποῖς; οὐ κωφὰ\footnote{\textgk{κωφός, ἠ, όν} mute, deaf, deaf and mute} πάντα, οὐ τυφλά, οὐκ ἄψυχα,\footnote{\textgk{ἄψυχος, ον} inanimate, lifeless} οὐκ ἀναίσθητα,\footnote{\textgk{ἀναίσθητος, ον} without feeling/perception} οὐκ ἀκίνητα;\footnote{\textgk{ἀκίνητος, ον} immovable, unable to move, unwavering, steadfast} οὐ πάντα σηπόμενα,\footnote{\textgk{σήπω} pres mid ptcp n.p.nom., decay, rot} οὐ πάντα φθειρόμενα.\footnote{\textgk{φθείρω} pres mid ptcp n.p.nom., destroy, ruin, corrupt, spoil}} \textbf{5} \textgk{ταῦτα Θεοὺς καλεῖτε, τούτοις δουλεύετε,\footnote{\textgk{δουλεύω} pres act ind 2p, be a slave, be subjected, perform the duties of a slave, serve, obey} τούτοις προσκυνεῖτε· τέλεον\footnote{\textgk{τέλειος, α, ον} perfect, complete, expert, full-grown, mature, adult, fully developed} δ᾿ αὐτοῖς ἐξομοιοῦσθε.\footnote{\textgk{ἐξομοιόω} pres mid ind 3p, become just like/similar, resemble fully}} \textbf{6} \textgk{διὰ τοῦτο μισεῖτε Χριστιανούς,\footnote{\textgk{Χριστιανός, οῦ, ὁ} Christ-partisan, Christian} ὅτι τούτους οὐχ ἡγοῦνται\footnote{\textgk{ἡγέομαι} pres mid ind 3p, lead, guide, think, consider, regard} θεούς.} \textbf{7} \textgk{ὑμεῖς γὰρ οἱ νῦν νομίζοντες\footnote{\textgk{νομίζω} pres act ptcp m.p.nom., have in common use, think, believe, hold, consider} καὶ σεβόμενοι,\footnote{\textgk{σέβω} pres mid ptcp m.p.nom., worship, show reverence/respect for} οὐ πολὺ πλέον αὐτῶν καταφρονεῖτε;\footnote{\textgk{καταφρονέω} pres act impv 2p, look down on, despise, scorn, treat with contempt, care nothing for, disregard, be unafraid of} οὐ πολὺ μᾶλλον αὐτοὺς χλευάζετε\footnote{\textgk{χλευάζω} pres act ind 2p, mock, sneer, scoff, scoff at, sneer at} καὶ ὑβρίζετε,\footnote{\textgk{ὑβρίζω} pres act ind 2p, mistreat, scoff at, insult} τοὺς μὲν λιθίνους\footnote{\textgk{λίθινος, ίνη, ον} (made of) stone} καὶ ὀστρακίνους\footnote{\textgk{ὀστρακίνος, η, ον} made of earth/clay} σέβοντες\footnote{\textgk{σέβω} pres act ptcp m.p.nom., worship, show reverence/respect for} ἀφυλάκτως,\footnote{\textgk{ἀφυλάκτως} without guarding} τοὺς δὲ ἀργυρέους\footnote{\textgk{ἀργυροῦς, ᾶ, οῦν} silver} καὶ χρυσοῦς\footnote{\textgk{χρυσός, οῦ, ὁ} gold, coined gold, money} ἐγκλείοντες\footnote{\textgk{ἐγκλείω} pres act ptcp m.p.nom., lock up, shut up, enclose} ταῖς νυξί, καὶ ταῖς ἡμέραις φύλακας\footnote{\textgk{φύλαξ, ακος, ὁ} guard, sentinel} παρακαθιστάντες,\footnote{\textgk{παρακαθίστημι} pres act ptcp m.p.nom., post} ἵνα μὴ κλαπῶσιν;\footnote{\textgk{κλέπτω} aor pass sub 3p, steal}} \textbf{8} \textgk{αἷς δὲ δοκεῖτε τιμαῖς προσφέρειν, εἰ μὲν αἰσθάνονται,\footnote{\textgk{αἰσθάνομαι} pres mid ind 3p, notice, understand} κολάζετε\footnote{\textgk{κολάζω} pres act ind 2p, penalize, punish} μᾶλλον αὐτούς· εἰ δὲ ἀναισθητοῦσιν,\footnote{\textgk{ἀναισθητέω} pres act ind 3p, be unfeeling, insensible} ἐλέγχοντες\footnote{\textgk{ἐλέγχω} pres act ptcp m.p.nom., bring to light, expose, set forth, convict, convince, reprove, correct, punish, discipline} αἵματι καὶ κνίσαις\footnote{\textgk{κνῖσα, ης, ἡ} the odor of burning fat} αὐτοὺς θρησκεύετε.\footnote{\textgk{θρησκεύω} pres act ind 2p, worship}} \textbf{9} \textgk{ταῦθ᾿ ὑμῶν τις ὑπομεινάτω,\footnote{\textgk{ὑπομένω} aor act impv 3s, remain/stay (behind), stand one's ground, hold out, endure, wait for} ταῦτα ἀνασχέσθω\footnote{\textgk{ἀνέχω} aor mid impv 3s, endure, bear with, put up with, accept a complaint} τις ἑαυτῷ γενέσθαι. ἀλλὰ ἄνθρωπος μὲν οὐδὲ εἷς ταύτης τῆς κολάσεως\footnote{\textgk{κόλασις, εως, ἡ} punishment} ἑκὼν\footnote{\textgk{ἑκών, οῦσα, όν} willing(ly), glad(ly)} ἀνέξεται,\footnote{\textgk{ἀνέχω} fut mid ind 3s, endure, bear with, put up with, accept a complaint} αἴσθησιν\footnote{\textgk{αἴσθησις, εως, ἡ} perception, sensation, discernment} γὰρ ἔχει καὶ λογισμόν·\footnote{\textgk{λογισμός, οῦ, ὁ} calculation, reasoning, reflection, thought, reasoning power, wisdom} ὁ δὲ λίθος ἀνέχεται,\footnote{\textgk{ἀνέχω} pres mid ind 3s, endure, bear with, put up with, accept a complaint} ἀναισθητεῖ\footnote{\textgk{ἀναισθητέω} pres act ind 3s be unfeeling, insensible} γάρ· οὐκοῦν\footnote{\textgk{οὐκοῦν} therefore, so, accordingly, so then} τὴν αἴσθησιν\footnote{\textgk{αἴσθησις, εως, ἡ} perception, sensation, discernment} αὐτοῦ ἐλέγχετε.\footnote{\textgk{ἐλέγχω} pres act ind 2p, expose, bring to light, set forth, convict, convince, reprove, correct, punish, discipline}} \textbf{10} \textgk{περὶ μὲν οὖν τοῦ μὴ δεδουλῶσθαι\footnote{\textgk{δουλόω} perf mid inf, enslave, cause to be like a slave} Χριστιανοὺς\footnote{\textgk{Χριστιανός, οῦ, ὀ} Christ-partisan, Christian} τοιούτοις θεοῖς πολλὰ μὲν [ἂν] καὶ ἄλλα εἰπεῖν ἔχοιμι· εἰ δέ τινι μὴ δοκοίη κἂν ταῦτα ἱκανά, περισσὸν\footnote{\textgk{περισσός, ή, όν} extraordinary, remarkable, abundant, profuse} ἡγοῦμαι\footnote{\textgk{ἡγέομαι} pres mid ind 1s, lead, guide, think, consider, regard} καὶ τὸ πλείω λέγειν.}


\end{document}
```

Comment: the text input lines are *very* long.  i've copied them into an emacs buffer, and triggered the command to count characters in a line.  the line that comprises chapter 2, beginning `textbf{2:1}` gives a count of 9853, which is nearly twice the size of the defined input buffer.  unless there's a real necessity not to break this text, i suggest putting a line break immediately before each numbered segment.  (i see ten segments numbered in chapter 2.)  otherwise, you'll need to increase the size of the input buffer.

Comment: If one comments out the material pertaining to `\textbf{7}`, no problems seem to remain. I would check if there's some bad code in that part of the document.

Comment: \footnote{\textgk{σέβω} pres mid ptcp m.p.nom., worship, show reverence/respect for} οὐ πολὺ πλέον αὐτῶν καταφρονεῖτε;\footnote{\textgk{καταφρονέω} pres act impv 2p, look down Check all unclosed footnotes ... on, despise, scorn, treat with contempt, care nothing for, disregard, be unafraid of} οὐ πολὺ μᾶλλον αὐτοὺς χλευάζετε\footnote{\textgk{χλευάζω} pres act ind 2p, mock, sneer, scoff, scoff at, sneer at} καὶ ὑβρίζετε,\footnote{\textgk{ὑβρίζω} pres act ind 2p, mistreat, scoff at, insult} τοὺς μὲν ... and compile often then it is less of a problem

Comment: a barbara says you can make the input lines _much_ shorter (you can change every space to a newline without affecting the output)

Comment: Thank you all for your help. Indeed, the lines were way to long. I think this happened from copying from another program. Luckily Sublime Text 2 allows for multiple cursors so I was able to make a new line before every \textbf. I would mark this as answered but seems that since it is my first post and my "rep" isn't high enough I can't.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Can you add an answer?

Answer (score 2):

the text input lines are very long.

i've copied them into an emacs buffer, and triggered the command to count characters in a line. the line that comprises chapter 2, beginning textbf{2:1} gives a count of 9853, which is nearly twice the size of the defined input buffer.

unless there's a real necessity not to break this text, i suggest putting a line break immediately before each numbered segment. (i see ten segments numbered in chapter 2.) otherwise, you'll need to increase the size of the input buffer.

input lines can be broken at any space with no effect on the output.  so you may find it convenient (and the file easier to read) if you start every sentence on a new line.  if it's necessary to break a line somewhere else (say just before a footnote), end the broken line with a `%` to cause the space produced by the end-of-line to be ignored.