# While loading fancyvrb, siunitx and bigfoot, I got input stack size=5000, TeX STOPPED: fatal errors occurred

Tags: errors, siunitx, fancyvrb, bigfoot, capacity

If I try to build the following document:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{bigfoot}

\begin{document}

    Test.

\end{document}
```

`Latex` just throws the error:

```
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <7> on input line 15.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <5> on input line 15.
\c__siunitx_mathtt_int=\count327

input stack size=5000]
TeX STOPPED: fatal errors occurred. Check the TeX log file for details
```

---

Related questions:

1. [TeX capacity exceeded, input stack size=5000](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/245591/tex-capacity-exceeded-input-stack-size-5000)
2. [Error Latex TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64893/error-latex-tex-capacity-exceeded-sorry-input-stack-size-5000)
3. [TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000] after loading "hanging module" in both parent and child documents in LyX Classicthesis](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/300935/tex-capacity-exceeded-sorry-input-stack-size-5000-after-loading-hanging-modu)
4. [Tex capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size = 5000]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24247/tex-capacity-exceeded-sorry-input-stack-size-5000)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Analysis

Compilation stops when the tokens in `\AtBeginDocument` are being evaluated. For historical reasons, `bigfoot` has

```
\def\FN@allmarks#1{\@elt{#1}%
  \ifnum#1<\count266
    \expandafter\FN@allmarks\expandafter{\number\numexpr#1+\@ne}%
  \fi}
```

because `etex.sty` had

```
\count266=1 % globally allocates \marks classes 1, 2, ...
```

The `bigfoot` package has not been updated after LaTeX has incorporated much of `etex.sty`, including allocation of the extended registers (above 255), but the counter holding the last allocated `marks` register is not `\count266` any longer.

What happens in your case is that `\count266` is allocated by `siunitx` as part of the loading of `expl3` and receives the value `16777216`, which of course makes too long a loop when `\FN@allmarks0` is executed.

Loading `fancyvrb` after `siunitx` doesn't trigger the error, but doesn't solve the issue either, because `\count266` will hold a value that most likely has nothing to do with the number of allocated `marks` registers. The LaTeX kernel reserves `\count256` for that.

## Solution

Patch `\FN@allmarks` to use the right register.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{bigfoot}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\FN@allmarks}{266}{256}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

    Test.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I change the package loading order to:

```
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{bigfoot}
```

it gets fixed.